# How to pass variable as a const one in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

When using react-navigation in my app, I need to pass some variable which is regarded const for the target screen.

As all params we passed to target screen using react-navigation is accessed via something like `this.props.navigation.state.params.xxx`, I wonder how to **mark** some of this variable "const" just like we initialize a component with `props`?

Store this const variable in `this.state` is quite confusing although it's a feasible choice because that this variable should not be changed within the screen.

---

Update:

Sorry for my confusing expression.

The core question is **how to mark variable passed by react-navigation as a const one**.

I mean, I have a screen class named 'MainScreen', and now I want to navigate to another screen named 'SecondaryScreen' via react-navigation. So I write codes like this:

```
const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
navigate('SecondaryScreen', {
    agentCode: this.state.agentInfo.agentCode,
    queryDate: '20180101'
})
```

I hope agentCode is a const in SecondaryScreen and queryDate is a variable.

So for queryDate in SecondaryScreen I write this:

```
constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
    var params = this.props.navigation.state.params
    this.state = {
        queryDate = params.queryDate
    }
}
```

Now queryDate is stored properly. But what about agentCode?

How to store `this.props.navigation.state.params.agentCode` as const class variable?

If I init SecondaryScreen by myself, I may use

```
<Secondary agentCode={this.state.agentInfo.agentCode}>
```

By doing so, agentCode is accessed via `this.props.agentCode` in Secondary. But with react-navigation, I don't know how to achieve the same effects.

As all class variables in react stores in props or state, I wonder how to pass const to SecondaryScreen through react-navigation?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish. Could you please describe the scenario or give an example? As far as I know, you cannot change the value of `props` anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it to a const at component mounting.

```
componentDidMount(){
   const agentCode = this.props.navigation.state.params.agentCode;
}
```

Comment: Could it be accessed through the whole class or just the scope of the function?